# Unexpected tIDENTIFIER in function declaration with optional argument

Tags: ruby

I am trying to declare a class with a few basic functions in it. The function that seems to be causing a problem has an optional argument that passes a symbol in.

```rb
class Bag < RandomizerCollection
    def initialize()
    end

    def select(description:Hash, amt=:all)
    end

    def empty()
    end 
end
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from test.rb:5:in `<main>'
test.rb:5:in `require_relative': /home/osboxes/Documents/Year4/Design/A1/Bag.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER (SyntaxError)
...ef select(description:hash, amt = :all)
...                            ^~~
/home/osboxes/Documents/Year4/Design/A1/Bag.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
...t(description:hash, amt = :all)
```

I'm sure this must be something basic but I just can't figure it out. I am new to Ruby and I found similar questions but none helped me find the issue. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define optional arguments (`arg=value`) after the definition of the keyword arguments (`arg: value`).

You can correct it in two ways:

1. Move optional arg before the keywor arg:

```
    def select(amt=:all, description:Hash)
    end
```

2. Make the second argument a keyword arg:

```
    def select(description:Hash, amt: :all)
    end
```

Worth reading: https://medium.com/podiihq/ruby-parameters-c178fdcd1f4e